# Autobahn and Twisted, call wamp client method and get result via HTTP

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn, wamp-protocol

I have done a client like this SomeClient, which talk with a WAMP v1 server.

What I'm unable to do, as you can see on line 25, is to call the SomeClient.i_need_to_call_this method from the HTTPServer class.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import server, resource
from autobahn.wamp1.protocol import WampClientFactory, WampCraClientProtocol
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import connectWS

class SomeClient(WampCraClientProtocol):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def doSomething(self, something):
        return something

    def i_need_to_call_this(self):
        d = self.call("http://somewhere")
        d.addCallback(self.doSomething)



class HTTPServer(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def render_GET(self, request):
        request.setHeader("content-type", "application/json")
        result = "Here i need to call SomeClient.i_need_to_call_this and render the result"
        return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    factory = WampClientFactory("wss://someurl")
    factory.protocol = SomeClient
    connectWS(factory)
    reactor.listenTCP(8080, server.Site(HTTPServer()))
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: create an object of `SomeClient`in `render_GET` method and call the function.

Comment: SomeClient runs independently, and also starting it inside HTTPServer _initi_'s, factory doesn't bind the SomeClient class methods.

Answer (score 1):

The typical idiom of doing this is to maintain an instance variable `factory.proto` that will be initialized with `None` and later filled by the connected protocol to the protocol itself.

By having the `factory` then available by reference from wherever you want to issue a WAMP call, you can then use `factory.proto`. You need to guard those uses by `if factory.proto ..`, since you cannot use the client protocol instance when there isn't a connection.